$L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{a})$ if and only if $(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)(\alpha_1 - \alpha_3)(\alpha_2 - \alpha_3) = \pm \sqrt{-3}$.
Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree 3 with roots $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$. Let $L = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$. Prove that there exists some $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{a})$ if and only if $(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)(\alpha_1 - \alpha_3)(\alpha_2 - \alpha_3) = \pm \sqrt{-3}$.
In this case, we can use things that are known about discriminants in Galois theory, but I don't know how to start.
This are some ideas:
(1) $f(x) = (x - \alpha_{1}) (x - \alpha_{2}) (x - \alpha_{3}) = x^{3} - (\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} + \alpha_{3})x^{2} + (\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2} + \alpha_{1}\alpha_{3} + \alpha_{2}\alpha_{3})x- \alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}\alpha_{3}$.
(2) $\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}\alpha_{3} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}$.
(3) We can take $\omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$ and $L(\omega) / \mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension with $[L(\omega) : \mathbb{Q}] = 6$.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question. Can you please add some more context? Your question looks interesting, and you "don't know how to start", but can you elaborate on "we can use things that are known about discriminants in Galois theory"?

Yes, @AnneBauval , you're right. In this case, I believe it is possible to use the fact that $L(\omega)/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension, and then apply the automorphisms of $\text{Gal}(L(\omega)/\mathbb{Q})$.

Thanks, @OscarLanzi you are right. It is possible to modify this result a little bit.

This is straightforward to prove using elementary techniques in field theory. But your statement needs to be modified. The correct result is: Let $d$ equal the discriminant of $f(x)$. Then $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{a})$ for some $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ if and only if there exists some $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $-3d = b^2$. A constructive proof can be found in: Ming-chang Kang, Cubic fields and radical extensions, Amer. Math. Monthly 107 (2000), no. 3, 254-256.

As noted by Im6612, the product of the root differences does not have anynprecise absolute clvalue and tge true theotem is best stated in termsbof discriminants.
We show here that the priduct of the root differences must be a rational number times $\sqrt{-3}$.
Let $\alpha_1$ be a real root, which in relevant cases must be the only real root; then if this is to belong to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{a}]$ it must have the form
$\alpha_1=c_2\sqrt[3]{a^2}+c_1\sqrt[3]{a}+c_0.$
From Galois theory or the Cardano formula for solvung cubic equations the other, complex conjugate roots will be
$\alpha_2=c_2\omega^2\sqrt[3]{a^2}+c_1\omega\sqrt[3]{a}+c_0$
$\alpha_3=c_2\omega\sqrt[3]{a^2}+c_1\omega^2\sqrt[3]{a}+c_0,$
where $\omega$ is either nonreal cube root of unity.
We simply take the differences and multiply them. Terms containg cube-root radicals cancel out and we are left with
$(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)(\alpha_1-\alpha_3)(\alpha_2-\alpha_3)=(c_1^3a-c_2^3a^2)\color{blue}{(1-\omega)(1-\omega^2)(\omega-\omega^2)},$
where the blue factors give the product $\pm3\sqrt{-3}$ depending on which of the two possible roots is chosen for $\omega$.
This product of the root differences enters into the discriminant, leading to the discriminant-vlbased statement by Im6612.

Do you know if this can be made constructive ? In other words, can you recover $a,c_1,c_2$ if you only have $c_1^3a-c_2^3a^2$ ?

You can't do this. That the numbers are not unique can be seen by dividing the $c$ values by $2$ and multiplying $a$ by $8$.

Thanks @Oscar , do you know how to test the other implication?

Here is an answer that uses Galois theory.
So we must show the equivalence between
(1) $L={\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[3]{a})$ for some $a\in {\mathbb Q}$
(2) $(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)(\alpha_1 - \alpha_3)(\alpha_2 - \alpha_3) = \pm \sqrt{-3} b^2$, for some $b\in {\mathbb Q}$.
Proof of (1)$\Rightarrow$(2) : as in Oscar Lanzi's answer.
Proof of (2)$\Rightarrow$(1) : let $M={\mathbb Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)={\mathbb Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ since $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3$ is rational.  Now, it follows from (2) that $\omega=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}\in M$. Since the extension $M/{\mathbb Q}$ is Galois by construction, the extension $M/{\mathbb Q}(\omega)$ is Galois also, and its  Galois group $H$ is isomorphic to $\frac{Gal(M/{\mathbb Q})}{Gal({\mathbb Q}(\omega)/{\mathbb Q})}$. Since the extension in the denominator is quadratic, it follows that $|H|=\frac{[M:{\mathbb Q}]}{2}$. On the other hand, $[M:{\mathbb Q}]=[M:L][L:{\mathbb Q}]$ must be a multiple of $3$ because $f$ is irreducible. Finally, $G=Gal(M/{\mathbb Q})$ can be identified to a subgroup of $S_3$ by its action of the  roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$.
Those three conditions together imply that $G$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, $M=L(\omega)$ and $|H|=3$.
But there is only one group of order $3$, and this is the cyclic one. By Kummer theory (see for example https://www.ihes.fr/~sefil/TA/2005/struct/l11.pdf), theis cyclic extension must be radical, there is a $d\in M$ such that $c=d^3\in {\mathbb Q}(\omega)$ such that $M={\mathbb Q}(\omega)(d)$. We can write $c=c_1+c_2\omega$ with $c_1,c_2\in {\mathbb Q}$. Taking complex conjugates, we deduce $\bar{d}^3=c_1+c_2\bar{\omega}$. Now $\bar{d}\in M$ because
$d\in M$ and $M$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$. We then have
$$(d\bar{d})^3=\big(c_1+c_2\omega\big)\big(c_1+c_2\bar{\omega}\big)=c_1^2-c_1c_2+c_2^2$$
If we denote by $a$ the RHS above, we can write $d\bar{d}=\sqrt[3]{a}$ since $d\bar{d}$ is a real number. Consider now the field $L'= {\mathbb Q}(d\bar{d})$. Like $L$, it is a real field with degree $3$ over ${\mathbb Q}$. If $L$ and $L'$ were different, the compositum $LL'$ would have degree $9$ over $\mathbb Q$, which is impossible since $M$ has degree $6$ over ${\mathbb Q}$. Thus $L=L'$, which finishes the proof.
Remark. This proof also shows (1) or (2) are both equivalent to $ \sqrt{-3}\in {\mathbb Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$.
